# jQuery select on change on click firing when option already selected

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know the title is confusing. I have a drop down that I am populating after the DOM is loaded via ajax. I am also attaching an on change event to capture when a user clicks an option with the mouse or when they select an option with the keyboard.

```
        $("#selTemp").one("change", function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                alert("click event fired");
            });
            $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    alert("enter key event fired");
                }
            });
        });
```

I was having some issues with the keypress firing 3 or more times until I changed the .on to .one to ensure it only fires once. Now I'm having an issue where if I select and option via mouse click, then I try to hit the dropdown again to change my selection the click event will fire immediately and won't allow me to select another option.

```
<label for="selTemp">Temp</label>
<select id="selTemp" class="form-control">
    <option>Select Disaster</option>
</select>
```

I'm at a loss since I've done this before and haven't had this issue. The only difference is that I am doing this within an MVC site and the script is being loaded through this method:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        //some script
    </script>
}
```

Is it loading the script multiple times?

Comment: `click` is a useless event on a `<select>`. It will fire when you try to open the select as well as when you select an option. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am basically trying to capture the users selection, but this application needs to be 508 compliant. When I was just capturing on change it was firing when the down key and I needed a way to specify only when selected via mouse click or keypress of enter key.

Comment: but change doesn't fire with keyboard until user blurs the select when it isn't a `multiple`

Comment: If I just do 

$("#select").on("change", function(){ alert("fired on change of select")});

That fires on every key down. To specify, it fires on every key down if they tab into the select and just hit down, never opening the drop down. If a user is disabled and they can only use their keyboard, I don't want to capture them scrolling through every option. That is why I put the keypress in there to only capture when they hit enter. But then I needed to accommodate mouse users as well and so I added the on click event.

Comment: What browser?..just tried in both chrome and firefox and change doesn't fire until blur the select or hit enter. Nobody but nobody uses click on select...it is a useless event

Comment: IE11. It's an intranet application and we only run IE. I understand that if you open the drop down the change event won't fire on the press of the down arrow, but if you don't open the drop down with the mouse, but instead tab to the select and hit the down arrow, it will fire the change event.

Comment: This is kind of old but it explains that IE isn't as accessible as FF or Chrome: https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/2ACC/Fix+for+Select+Elements+with+Inaccessible+Onchange+Events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that, because of the way different browsers handle the keyboard functionality when a user TABs into a select and subsequently uses the arrow keys to navigate, I needed to look for another, more accessible solution. I've settled on adding a button with a click event that then looks for the users selected option.

Here is an article that explains in better detail as to why this solution is much more accessible:

http://pauljadam.com/blog/onchange-event-on-a-select-inputjump-menu-accessibility-problems/

And here is the code in case anyone needs it (it's very simple):

HTML

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select id="selTemp" class="form-control">
                <option>Select Temp</option>
            </select>
            <button id="btnGetStuff" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get Some stuff</button>
        </div>   
    </form>
```

jQuery

```
    $("#btnGetStuff").on("click", function () {
        var temp = $("#selTemp option:selected").val();
    });
```